# Fightcade help to install ubuntu 17.10

Tags: python, wine

I want to get a program running on Ubuntu 17.10 Fightcade 
I have downloaded the tar.gz extracted the contents from it to a new folder on my Desktop 
I try to run the commands to install and terminal tells me two things either about python wine so i check that python is upto date and installed same with wine installed it from the software and apps (no reboot) and i am stuck when running the following command shows this error(s)

## 1) sudo python main.py Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
```

## 2)sudo apt-get install wine python-qt4-phonon python-qt4

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package wine is a virtual package provided by:
  wine-stable 2.0.2-2ubuntu1
  wine-development 2.18-1
You should explicitly select one to install.
```

Im sure its already installed and that its the stable version i can see options when i search the activities area in ubuntu

## 3)sudo python main.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    import sip
```

---

Guys how can i get Fightcade running on 17.10 thats my end goal please help me toward that end and if i dont need all this stuff like python and wine fine but tell me why the errors none the less-id really like to understand whats at play here (converted windows user) 41year clear and counting

Answer (score 1):

Was able to get it running by editing the main.py file 
Changed "wine" to "wine-stable" and then saved the file and executed with ./main.py 
I may of uncommented the line also cant remember (make sure the line needed is uncommented any way and run the script and it will load next issue however is making connections with the Fightcade program. I am currently stuck as am unable to accept any challenges just hangs no startup even when i click or type /accept to incoming challenges. I have required and tested working roms and bios's if anyone has suggestions with the next piece of puzzle let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

But the same idea. I change the code of file linux-install.sh and change wine x wine-stable. in the next lines

```
    # ubuntu/debian based distributions
if [ -x /usr/bin/apt-get ]; then
    apt-get install wine-stable python-qt4-phonon python-qt4
    exit $?
```

and later run in the terminal

```
sudo ./linux-install.sh
```

and all run normally. :)